# Having trouble hiding/disabling elements when using timeouts

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I'm trying to disable a button, hide a select list & show some text once a button is clicked... because of how long the javascript can take I am using timeouts to prevent the browser locking & the browser ending it prematurely or presenting a warning... however the code I have doesn't seem to be hiding/disabling/showing the elements once the button is clicked.

**Edit:** I have confirmed that the elements ARE getting hidden & then reshown, however they are being reshown too early.... the javascript hasn't finished doing what it's doing & they are reshown almost instantly after they are hidden.

**Edit 2:** Fixed it by moving the code that reshows the select list etc from the "addCatsSICMain" function to the "addCatsSIC" function as so..

```
if (spot < cats.options.length) {    
    other code here...
} else {
    reshow select list etc code here
}
```

Here is the code:

This first function is the one that is called once the button is clicked.

```
function addCatsSICMain() {

    // Set elements
    var addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
    var cat_sel = document.getElementById('cat_sic_sel_wrapper');
    var addWait = document.getElementById('addWait');

    // Disable add button
    addBtn.disabled = true;

    // Hide selected list
    cat_sel.style.display = 'none';

    // Show waiting text
    addWait.style.display = 'block';

    // Use a timeout function so button can be hid/show when we want successfully & not on function completion

    setTimeout(function(){

        // Add selected cats
        addCatsSIC(0);

        // Reshow selected list, reenable add button & hide wwaiting text
        addWait.style.display = 'none';
        cat_sel.style.display = 'block';
        addBtn.disabled = false;

    }, 10);

}

function addCatsSIC(spot) {

    // Set the search results box
    var cats = document.getElementById('cat_sic_list');

    // Set the selected categories list that we are adding to..
    var sel_cats = document.getElementById('cat_sic_sel'); 

    // Set selcted counter var
    var sel_count = 0;

    // Set category add failed var
    var failed = 0;

    // Set batch size for looping
    var batchSize = 50;    

    // Still more to do?

    if (spot < cats.options.length) {    

        // Loop through categories from the search results select box

        for (var i = spot; i < spot + batchSize && i < cats.options.length; i++) {

            // Check if the cat is selected

            if (cats.options[i].selected == true) {

                // Set this category's values to some variables
                var cat_id = cats.options[i].getAttribute('value');
                var cat_name = cats.options[i].text;     

                if (checkCatSICAdd(cat_id) === false) {           

                    // Now we create the new element
                    var new_option = document.createElement('option');

                    // Add attribute
                    new_option.setAttribute('value',cat_id);

                    // Create text node
                    var new_text_node = document.createTextNode(cat_name);

                    // Append new text node to new option element we created
                    new_option.appendChild(new_text_node);

                    // Append new option tag to select list
                    sel_cats.appendChild(new_option);

                } else {
                    failed++;
                }

            }

        }

        var nextBitOfWork = function() { addCatsSIC(spot + batchSize) };

        // Hand control back to the browser so it can update the page & not timeout & then restart the function
        setTimeout(nextBitOfWork, 50);

    }

    if (failed > 0) {

        // Find out if more than 2 cats were selected

        for (var i = 0; i < cats.options.length; i++) {
            if (cats.options[i].selected == true) {
                sel_count++;   
            }
            if (sel_count == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }        

        // Give them an alert they have added that category already
        /*addedCatSICAlert(sel_count);*/

    }

}
```

Comment: The addCatsSICMain() function seems to work fine. If the select isn't being shown again, it is likely because there is a failure in the addCatsSIC() function. Also, the timeout on addCatsSICMain is shorter than on addCatsSIC, so they may be interferring with each other.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add that when making the select visible again, set it's display property to '' (empty string). The default value is 'inline', not block. Setting it to empty string lets it go back to whatever it's beeen set to, inherited or the default.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the comments. I changed the timeouts to be the same, but no change. Also wanted to clarify that I'm not having a problem getting the select list to show again, it doesn't hide in the first place. However checking it again it seems like the add button & the select list hide for a split second & then show again but stuff is "still happening" & they shouldn't be showing again yet. Also.... one last note, when I am hiding the select list I am hiding it's containing div so showing it again with "block" should work ok. :)

Comment: @RobG Please see my edit in the top part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by moving the code that reshows the select list etc from the "addCatsSICMain" function to the "addCatsSIC" function as so..

```
if (spot < cats.options.length) {    
    other code here...
} else {
    reshow select list etc code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not using jQuery for this.  You can disable button, hide select box and show elements by doing the following

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('select').hide();
    $('p').show();
})
```

### check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/N697c/1/

Comment: Perhaps because the OP doesn't use jQuery. That part of the code works fine.

Comment: Well since what I was doing was pretty simple I didn't bother using jQuery.